# Increment Integer Column Value by Variable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm using the following code to increment an integer column value by a variable.But the code seems not updating the value.What i'm i doing wrong?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE maintable SET counter=counter+@cvalue WHERE uname=@username", c);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "me");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cvalue", value);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

***Update:***

[image]

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @PSK No exception is thrown..

Comment: what is datatype of your variable value?

Comment: @DarkRob Please see the update.I'm using the SQL Management studio to check the results.

Comment: Please check the value of your variable once.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE maintable SET counter=ISNULL(counter,0)+@cvalue WHERE uname=@username
```

Answer (score 0):

is counter and cvalue both having datatype as int or decimal ? else increment won't be done for string

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE maintable SET counter=ISNULL(counter,0)+ISNULL(@cvalue,0) WHERE uname=@username", c);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "me");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cvalue", value);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yeah,the datatype is int.

Comment: to troubleshoot just try with UPDATE maintable SET counter=ISNULL(counter,0)+1 WHERE uname='staticusername' in your query and check if it works from code and in SQL server management studio

Comment: and also try with uname='"+@username+"'

Comment: because your uname is varchar data type

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly pass the data rather then passing like parameter.

```
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE maintable SET counter=(ISNULL(counter,0) + " + value + ") WHERE uname='me'", c);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please check once your value of variable "value" .